# [auth][error] UnknownAction: Cannot parse action at /api/auth/providers .Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#unknownaction

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Trying to set up next-auth using a tutorial for next-auth  authjs-v5 beta and getting this unknown action error and I am not able to figure whats the issue and the website also doesnt mention a fix just says the error name and nothing else

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "nextlearn",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/core": "^0.26.3",
    "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.3.3",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.9.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.314.0",
    "next": "^14.1.0",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.9",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.3",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^5.9.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

auth.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter"
import authConfig from "./auth.config"
import {db} from "@/lib/db"

export const { handlers:{GET,POST}, auth } = NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  ...authConfig,
})
```

auth.config.ts

```
import Github from "next-auth/providers/github"

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default {
  providers: [Github(
    {
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID??"",
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET??"",
    }
  )],
}
```

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
export {GET,POST} from "@/auth"
```

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCfvH.jpg)

any fix would be appreciated.

i tried changing the version to lower version to v4.XX.XX it works but i want it to work on v5 beta and i tried deleting node_modules and it still didn't worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was having this same issue when upgrading to next-auth v5. What solved it for me was removing the `AUTH_URL` key from my .env file.

This comment was what pointed me in the right direction: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/9819#issuecomment-1912903196

Comment: It totally solved the issue, thank you!

Comment: I have a similar issue and I dont have AUTH_URL:
On my console I have: '[auth][error] UnknownAction: Cannot parse action at /api/auth/callback/credentials/ .Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#unknownaction'. and on the browser '"Error: This action with HTTP POST is not supported."'. 
Using next-auth 5.0.0-beta.13 and next 14.1.0

Comment: this is does not solve error because when i did this i get errors when i sign out

Answer (score 3):

Install next canary or wait for `next@14.1.1` to fix this [GitHub Issue.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/61721)

```
npm i next@14.1.1-canary.37
```

Reinstall `next-auth@beta`

```
npm uninstall next-auth@beta

npm install next-auth@beta
```

Remove `AUTH_URL` in `.env`:

```
AUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Add `._doc` in jwt function in `auth.ts`

Comment: could you show me example on how to add ._doc where exactly i should add

Comment: after removing the AUTH_URL then in prod it just redirects to localhost. how to make it work in prod